# What is the reason for the odd syntax of [[maybe_unused]] on type aliases?

Tags: c++, c++17

Since C++17, there is now a standardized way to politely suggest the compiler to stop yelling aboud unused entities. When applying this to variables, functions, and old-skool type-aliases, we have to use the expected syntax which comes in the form:

```
[[maybe_unused]] int x;
[[maybe_unused]] void f();
[[maybe_unused]] typedef void t;
```

Nothing strange here. However, when applying this attribute-specifier to structs, enums, and especially modern-day type-aliases, we have to resort to all kinds of gobbledygook to make it work:

```
struct [[maybe_unused]] s;
union [[maybe_unused]] u;
enum class [[maybe_unused]] e;
using a [[maybe_unused]] = void; // what's up with this?
```

What is the reason for the odd placement of the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute for type-aliases? Could it really not be any other way?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6jq11c91P)

Comment: I'm not sure offhand about type aliases, but I can guess the others are because putting the attribute in front is already taken by the potential variable declaration (e.g., `[[maybe_unused]] struct s {} obj;` would affect `obj`).

Answer (score 10):

Because it's like a spiral: inner attributes are applied to inner names/types, outer attributes are applied to outer names.

```
   [[maybe_unused]] struct [[maybe_unused]] s {} s_;
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-^
//                         applied to the type
//
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------------------------^^
// applied to the variable
```

```
[[maybe_unused]] struct s1;     // invalid, there is no variable name
[[maybe_unused]] struct {} s2;  // valid, there is a variable name
```

As for the *alias-declaration:*
    **using** *identifier [attribute-specifier-seq] = defining-type-id ;*
no clue how to justify that.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I should've kept my question more clearly directed to just the syntax of the `using` type-alias, as this answer doesn't address that part.

Comment: @303 And now you have.  Cool.

Answer (score 6):

The ability to place an *attribute-specifier-seq* in an alias declaration was added by the resolution to [CWG1042](https://wg21.link/cwg1042). Unfortunately, when I looked through the CWG minutes, I couldn't find any recorded discussion about the placement of the *attribute-specifier-seq*. But it's pretty easy to come up with a guess as to why it goes after the *identifier*: to mirror the syntax of a typedef declaration:

```
typedef void a [[maybe_unused]];
```

A typedef declaration is a type of *simple-declaration*, that is, it has the same grammatical structure as the declaration of one or more variables or functions. In *simple-declaration*s, attributes follow the name of the entity declared:

```
int f [[deprecated]] (), x [[maybe_unused]];
```

Note that `f` is a deprecated function taking no arguments and returning `int`, and `x` is a possibly intentionally unused variable of type `int`.

You can also put an attribute at the beginning of a *simple-declaration*, but in that case it appertains to *all* entities declared in the declaration, whereas putting the attribute after the *declarator-id* makes it appertain to only a single entity.

Since an *alias-declaration* only declares one entity at a time, the hypothetical syntax

```
[[maybe_unused]] using a = void;
```

would have been reasonable too, and would have the same meaning; perhaps CWG simply did not wish to provide two ways of writing the same thing.

Comment: *"... perhaps CWG simply did not wish to provide two ways of writing the same thing."* That seems like a very plausible rationale for having made this decision. Still hoping there was some sort of mention or discussion about this design choice somewhere that can be referred to.

Answer (score -1):

The placement of the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute for type-aliases in C++17 might seem a bit unconventional, and one may wonder why it couldn't follow the same pattern as variables, functions, and old-style type-aliases. The reason behind this lies in the way type-aliases are syntactically defined in C++.

Type-aliases, defined using the 'using' keyword, introduce a name that refers to an existing type. Unlike variables, functions, and old-style type-aliases, the syntax for introducing a new name using 'using' is more involved. In C++, when declaring a type-alias, the keyword 'using' is followed by the alias name, an equals sign, and the type being aliased.

For example:

```
using my_alias = int;
```

In this context, the [[maybe_unused]] attribute is applied to the alias name ('my_alias'), indicating that the name might be unused without generating a compiler warning.

The syntax for applying attributes to the type being aliased would be cumbersome and less intuitive, as it would require inserting the attribute between the 'using' keyword and the alias name. Therefore, to maintain consistency and clarity in the language, the [[maybe_unused]] attribute is placed directly before the type-alias name.

It's worth noting that the placement might seem a bit unusual, but it aligns with the goal of providing a standardized and concise way to handle potentially unused entities across different language constructs in C++17.

Comment: *"... the [[maybe_unused]] attribute is placed directly before the type-alias name."* It isn't, however. It's placed after the name of the type-alias.

Comment: The statement: *"Therefore, to maintain consistency and clarity in the language ..."* seems to have a contradictory notion with the statement earlier: *"... it couldn't follow the same pattern as variables, functions, and old-style type-aliases."*

Comment: Also, your argument boils down to two things: *"... to maintain consistency and clarity in the language ..."* and *"... it aligns with the goal of providing a standardized and concise way to handle potentially unused entities across different language constructs ..."*. Could you please provide a source (preferably, in the form of a documented rationale) where these claims are based on?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).